# Theme customisation based on user locale in Actions on Google console

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to have a different background image in my google action depending on locale.

I am in the "Theme Customisation" tab in the actions console and have updated my background image for both portrait and landscape mode, but it seems there aren't any ways to configure this further.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add multiple locales to your Action. You can do so by following instructions from the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/add-languages?tool=builder). After that, you will be able to select a locale from the dropdown, and provide theme customization for it.